# Quanta LB6M : how to make trunk port

Tags: switch, trunk

My hardware is

```
(quanta10g-uha) #show hardware

Switch: 1

System Description............................. Quanta LB6M, 1.2.0.14, Linux   
                                                2.6.21.7                       
Machine Type................................... Quanta LB6M                    
Machine Model.................................. LB6M
Serial Number.................................. QTFCRW2370157
FRU Number..................................... 1LB6BZZ0STL
Part Number.................................... BCM56820
Maintenance Level.............................. A
Manufacturer................................... 0xbc00
Burned In MAC Address.......................... 08:9E:01:39:1F:A2
Software Version............................... 1.2.0.14
Operating System............................... Linux 2.6.21.7
Network Processing Device...................... BCM56820_B0
Additional Packages............................ FASTPATH QOS
```

How to make an interface as trunk port ?
Some discussione tell about 'switchport mode trunk',
But I only got

```
(quanta10g-uha) (Config)#interface 0/5

(quanta10g-uha) (Interface 0/5)#switchport ?

protected                Configure Switchport to Protected mode.
```

Sincerely

-bino-

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VLAN trunk isn't explicitly formed on that switch. Simply add the VLAN `<VLID>` to the interface:

```
interface 0/5
  vlan participation include <VLID>
  vlan pvid <VLID>
exit
```