# SOLVED - Quanta LB6M Trunk and Vlan

Tags: vlan, trunk

I have 2 Quanta LB6M and a Juniper EX4200 and need to create vlan and trunk

For vlan interface i have this:

```
interface 0/27
vlan pvid 31
vlan participation exclude 1
vlan participation include 31
exit
```

And for trunk :

```
interface 0/19
vlan participation include 31
vlan tagging 1,31
exit
```

I already created the vlan 31 and named it

```
VLAN ID VLAN Name                        VLAN Type
------- -------------------------------- -------------------
1       default                           Default
31      ADOPT                             Static
```

Here is the entire switch configuration
the port 0/19 is the trunk
and the 0/27 the vlan 31 port

```
(QUANTA LB6M) #show running-config
!Current Configuration:
!
!System Description "Quanta LB6M, 1.2.0.18, Linux 2.6.21.7"
!System Software Version "1.2.0.18"
!System Up Time          "0 days 0 hrs 1 mins 4 secs"
!Additional Packages     FASTPATH QOS
!Current SNTP Synchronized Time: Not Synchronized
!
set prompt "QUANTA LB6M"
network protocol none
network parms 10.1.212.244 255.255.0.0 10.1.0.240
vlan database
vlan 31
vlan name 31 "ADOPT"
exit
ip ssh server enable
ip ssh protocol 2
sshcon timeout 160
configure
sntp client mode unicast
sntp client port 123
! sntp server status is Other
sntp server "10.1.0.220"
aaa authentication enable "enableList" enable
line console
exit
line telnet
exit
line ssh
exit
spanning-tree configuration name "08-9E-01-A0-4C-C7"
snmp-server sysname "QUANTA LB6M"
!
interface 0/19
vlan participation include 31
vlan tagging 1,31
exit
interface 0/27
vlan pvid 31
vlan participation exclude 1
vlan participation include 31
exit
router rip
exit
router ospf
exit
exit
```

The trunk doesn't work at all, i'm missing something but can't find what..
Can someone point me to the good direction ?
In trouble since 2 weeks and nothing found on Google :/

Maybe it will be more clear with this picture.
All other vlan from the Juniper switch to the router is working.
The Trunk and VLAN 31 are configured on all devices

[image]

**Zac67** you have already answered to another post for the same issue, i tried to apply your solution but it doesn't work.
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/57190/93698

**Update** I found something strange, if i tag the port 0/11 from second LB6M with "vlan tagging 1,31" I loose the lan connectivity. I have a juniper switch after this LB6M, the port on the juniper is set to Trunk and vlan 31 is part of them. I have many other vlan passing through this port without any issues.

And found this too, no vlan 1 by default on Juniper switch ?

[image]

[image]

Here is the config of the Junpier switch EX4200 for the uplink port, all others vlan from others switchs are working, the only thing is the default vlan (0 on Juniper and 1 for Quanta)

```
    xe-0/1/2 {
    mtu 1518;
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            port-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members [ 11-17 19-28 31-32 50 99-100 ];
            }
            native-vlan-id default;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the full switch config to your question and also include details on how the connected devices are configured. You can check basic VLAN connectivity by inspecting the MAC address table for each VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved :)
It was a mistake on the trunk side. now everything works like a charm. I can confirm that Mikrotik, juniper and Quanta works well together.

**Note : If i set Vlan tagging 1 on the trunk port 0/11 just before Juniper switch, i loose the LAN, i don't use it and everything works great.**